# How to hide lines with comments in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, documentation, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't mean collapse, I mean hide. For example for single line comments it'd completely hide it, the editor entirely skipping the comment's line number.

I'm entirely self-taught when it comes to programming, so I'm sure I've picked up numerous bad habits, one of which is almost entirely forgoing commenting. I dislike the clutter, and have only coded alone so far. I'm wanting to comment my code more, but prefer to work with distraction-free code, so was wondering if there was a way to completely hide the comments when I don't need them? (Not hiding TODO comments would be a plus).

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'd really would like this as well.
Working with gRCP and .protobuf files with autogenerated nonsens comments every second or third row is a comment, making it hard to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, whether I would recommend working without comments. However, you could switch between two schemes. The first one would be the one you are currently working with. The other would be a copy of it, but with the -distracting- comments matching the background color.

[For instance like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Jgv.jpg)

It would still take the space, though.

Comment: This works really well with inline comments. Just needed to figure out how to quickly switch between schemes. The TODO comments are colored differently so they can still be seen as well.

Answer (score 0):

"CTRL SLASH" will comment the current line.

"CTRL SHIFT SLASH" will comment all that is currently selected.

To hide multiple commented lines simply use the minus/minimize arrows on the left side of the code window (right side of the line numbers).

To see the hidden lines use the add/maximize blocks.